# Run command for every line?

Tags: regex, string, bash, macos, terminal

I have a bunch of `1255-138279.trans.txt` files that contain lines like these:

```
1255-138279-0006 THE SHAPE WENT SLOWLY ALONG BUT WITHOUT MUCH EXERTION FOR THE SNOW THOUGH SUDDEN WAS NOT AS YET MORE THAN TWO INCHES DEEP
1255-138279-0007 AT THIS TIME SOME WORDS WERE SPOKEN ALOUD ONE
1255-138279-0008 TWO THREE
1255-138279-0009 FOUR FIVE
1255-138279-0010 BETWEEN EACH UTTERANCE THE LITTLE SHAPE ADVANCED ABOUT HALF A DOZEN YARDS
1255-138279-0011 HERE THE SPOT STOPPED AND DWINDLED SMALLER
1255-138279-0012 THEN A MORSEL OF SNOW FLEW ACROSS THE RIVER TOWARDS THE FIFTH WINDOW
1255-138279-0013 THE RIVER WOULD HAVE BEEN SEEN BY DAY TO BE OF THAT DEEP SMOOTH SORT WHICH RACES MIDDLE AND SIDES WITH THE SAME GLIDING PRECISION ANY IRREGULARITIES OF SPEED BEING IMMEDIATELY CORRECTED BY A SMALL WHIRLPOOL
1255-138279-0014 THE WINDOW WAS STRUCK AGAIN IN THE SAME MANNER
1255-138279-0015 THEN A NOISE WAS HEARD APPARENTLY PRODUCED BY THE OPENING OF THE WINDOW
1255-138279-0016 SAID THE BLURRED SPOT IN THE SNOW TREMULOUSLY
1255-138279-0017 I ASKED WHICH WAS YOUR WINDOW FORGIVE ME
1255-138279-0018 WELL I SAID THAT YOU MIGHT
1255-138279-0019 O MUST I IT IS WHEN SHALL WE BE MARRIED FRANK
1255-138279-0020 I HAVE MONEY
1255-138279-0021 AND WE LIVE IN TWO PARISHES DO WE WHAT THEN
1255-138279-0022 IF I SAID SO OF COURSE I WILL
1255-138279-0023 THE FACT IS I FORGOT TO ASK
1255-138279-0024 GOOD NIGHT FRANK GOOD NIGHT
```

For each line, I want to create a new file, named `1255-138279-0008.txt` (or whatever the code at the start of the line is), and containing the remainder of that line (in this case `TWO THREE`).

Comment: What do you want when the first field is not unique? Or do you know that will not happen?

Comment: @WalterA That won't happen. Overwriting would be fine though, thanks for noticing that and pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) :

```
$ awk '{v=$1; $1=""; print $0 > "path/to/dir/"v".txt"}' file.txt
$ ls -1 path/to/dir/*.txt
```

Comment: I get an error

    awk: syntax error at source line 1
     context is
 {v=$1; $1=""; print $0 > >>>  v".txt" <<<
     awk: illegal statement at source line 1

Comment: Maybe try gawk explicitely

Comment: How can I change the output file path? To be in subdirectories

Answer (score 2):

This simple `while` loop in shell would do the job:

```
while read -r id line; do
   echo "$line" >> "$id.txt"
done < file
```

Answer (score 1):

I prefer doing this in two steps.
First, use `sed` or `awk` to generate a shell script:

```
sed "s/^\s*\(\S\+\)\s\+\(.*\)$/echo '\2' > '\1.txt'/g" input.txt > output.sh
```

Or with a POSIX-compliant regex (without GNU extensions):

```
sed "s/^[[:space:]]*\([^[:space:]]\+\)[[:space:]]\+\(.*\)$/echo '\2' > '\1.txt'/g" input.txt > output.sh
```

Or using ERE:

```
sed -E "s/^[[:space:]]*([^[:space:]]+)[[:space:]]+(.*)$/echo '\2' > '\1.txt'/g" input.txt > output.sh
```

Output:

```
...
echo 'TWO THREE' > '1255-138279-0008.txt'
echo 'FOUR FIVE' > '1255-138279-0009.txt'
...
```

Then execute that script to generate the files.

```
. output.sh
```

Comment: This one doesn't work at all for me. Maybe the reason is because I'mon macOS?

Comment: @WalterA Very elegant, but I'd not go there until I'd be fully confident the `sed` command is reliable enough to cover every possible input file. The intermediate file helps analyze incidental problems and fine-tune the regex.

Comment: @minseong Sorry about that; `\S` and `\s` are GNU extensions. Please replace by their POSIX equivalents `[^[:space:]]` and `[[:space:]]`, respectively.